# How to jump to the rightmost window with just one keystroke?

Tags: vim, ide, editor

I found the window manager in vim is quite powerful. We can use it to split the window to whatever we want it to be. But when the numbers of the windows comes to more then 4, it will caused one problem: it's quit hard to jump to the rightmost window. Because the rightmost window is used to display taglist in my vim. I don't like the way that type <kbd>CTRL+w</kbd> for twice or more times to jump to the rightmost window. Is there a more easier way to do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
:nmap <C-\> <C-w>200l
```

then you press ctrl-\ will let you go to the most right window.

actually you don't need to press c-w many times. if you have 10 windows opened, and now you are in 3rd window, you just type ctrl-w 10 l. to go to the right most window.

from help:

> CTRL-W_l| CTRL-W l       go to Nth right window (stop at last window)

you just need give a N

Answer (score 4):

If the previous window was TagList, you can use `<C-w>p` to jump to it.

You can also use `<C-w>b` to jump to the last window at the bottom-right.